# Does removing a user from Azure Devops remove the content they uploaded?

Tags: azure-devops

Currently, I am trying to do a user audit to remove old accounts from our environment. I found this KB about removing users from [Azure Devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-organization-users?view=azure-devops). I could not find any information about what happens to the content they uploaded if they get removed. If I remove a user from the organization, will the code or any content they have uploaded be removed as well?

Answer (score 2):

> Does removing a user from Azure Devops remove the content they uploaded?

The answer is **no**.

The code or any content they have uploaded will be control by the source control git/TFVC. The source control tool only track the files changes and record the history of changes. But the users is not within the scope of the source control, it only record the uses name who make any change in the source control.

Besides, if remove a user from the organization will remove the code or any content they have uploaded, which will cause all code development will be aborted due to developer changes. This will be a disaster. And, according to [that document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-organization-users?view=azure-devops), it indirect explain that:

> After you remove a user from Azure AD, you can't assign artifacts to
>   that user anymore. Examples are work items and pull requests. However,
>   **we preserve the history of artifacts that were already assigned to the
>   user**.

So, do not worry about deleting users from your organization will delete the code or any content they upload.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No. It would be totally useless as a source control or work tracking tool if data was abruptly removed because a user was removed.